# Lookup value to match conditions

Tags: google-sheets

As image shown below, I'd like to to find the value of `Book Name` is Red book, and `Category` is Novel. I found [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) can't match multi conditions. What function should I use?

So like:

```
if (Book name == "Red book" && Category == "Novel") {
    
    get "in Stock" value // which is 4 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP("Red Book"&"Novel",{A1:A500&B1:B500,C1:C500},2,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Two common ways to filter data:

[`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) is for getting filtered data by multiple conditions:

```
=FILTER(A3:C,A3:A="yellow",B3:B="history")
```

[`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) has fewer filtering options, but is more powerful for reports:

```
=QUERY({A2:C},"select * where Col1 = 'yellow' and Col2 = 'novel'")
```